# Java Application with JCEF crashes without exception message

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

I have a problem with my Java application that uses JCEF. I imported JCEF as a maven decency (https://github.com/jcefmaven/jcefmaven).
To demonstrate it, I created a simple scratch application:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;
import org.cef.CefApp;
import org.cef.CefClient;
import org.cef.JCefLoader;
import org.cef.browser.CefBrowser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Scratch.class.getName());
            log.info("Initialize CefApp");
            CefApp cefApp = JCefLoader.installAndLoadCef();
            log.info("Create CefClient");
            CefClient client = cefApp.createClient();
            log.info("Create CefBrowser");
            CefBrowser browser = client.createBrowser(
                    "file:///**path to a html file**",
                    SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX,
                    false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes, when I run this (e.g. after a restart or after a longer time in that I was not starting the application), it just crashes:

```
Feb 16, 2021 5:42:22 PM Scratch main
INFORMATION: Initialize CefApp
Feb 16, 2021 5:42:23 PM Scratch main
INFORMATION: Create CefClient
initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1,6,main] with library path /**path to project**/cef_bundle/84.3.8+gc8a556f+chromium-84.0.4147.105-linux64

Process finished with exit code 131 (interrupted by signal 3: SIGQUIT)
```

I think the problem comes not from my code. I hope someone can help me! :)

For your information this is a duplicate of [this](https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=18208) article in the official CEF Forum.
I posted this article again here, because I don't get a response there.

Comment: Instead of IOException why don't you catch Exception or Throwable and then see what the Stack trace tells you.

Comment: I changed that to Exception, but the output is the same.

Comment: Dear, What is the StackTrace ? Are you not getting a StackTrace ? Instead of Exception put a Throwable. See if a Throwable is getting caught. Put some Logs in it OR better run your application in a debugger.